# Pass an object function by reference

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to pass an object function by reference. I can only make it work with a simple function.

Code:

```cpp
class Light {

  ...... omitted some code here, not relevant .......

  void toggle2() {
    Serial.println("TOGGLE");
  };
}
class Button {
  public:
    OneButton pin;
    void single();

    Button(int _pin, void (&_single)() ){
      pin = OneButton(_pin, false, false);

      _single();
      pin.attachClick(_single);
    }
};
Light lights[] = {
  Light("Cozinha", CONTROLLINO_A15, CONTROLLINO_R0)
};
Button buttons[] = {
  Button(CONTROLLINO_A0, lights[0].toggle2)
};
```

the code above gives an error on button declaration

`no instance of constructor "Button::Button" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (int, void ())`

`toggle2` function is a void function but maybe the program is confusing because of the Light type?

If I make the code with a simple function it works well, like this:

```cpp
void toggle() {
  Serial.println("TOGGLE");
};

Button buttons[] = {
  Button(CONTROLLINO_A0, toggle)
};
```

Any suggestion??

Comment: Pointers to member functions gets weird. Here's some good coverage: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members. TL;DR version: You bneed to pass in an instance to invoke the function on and the syntax is a bit funky. Consider using [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: thanks for the reply, I forgot to mention I'm using the program for Arduino, `std::function` still applies?

Comment: In that case probably not. It's a lot easier to manage, but probably not available. `Serial.println("TOGGLE");`  and the arduino tag should have been enough for me to know you have to do this the hard way.

Comment: do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I've removed all of the noise from the code sample to focus on the how-tos of passing and calling a function pointer.

```cpp
class Light {
public:
  void toggle2() {
  };
};
class Button {
  public:
    Button(int _pin, 
           void (Light::*single)(),  // the function. Compiler needs to know the class 
                                     // the function belongs to or it'll assume a free 
                                     // function
           Light& light) // class instance to invoke the member function on
    {
        (light.*single)(); // note the weird-looking invocation syntax.
                           // all of it is essential and easily <expletive deleted>ed up.
                           // C++FAQ recommends using a macro to keep from leaving 
                           // anything out. They don't recommend macros lightly.
                           // note you will want to store these two variables as Button 
                           // class members rather than using them immediately.
                           // I did the call in the constructor to keep the example simple.
    }
};

Light lights[] = {
  Light()
};

Button buttons[] = {
  Button(1, // the pin
         &Light::toggle2, // address of the fully-qualified member function 
         lights[0]) // instance to invoke member function on
};
```

The gory details, and some very good suggestions, can be found at [Pointers to Member Functions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members)

Note that since `Button` must now carry around the a reference to the `Light` instance it uses, making `lights` and `Buttons` local variable variables in a sufficiently widely scoped function is an attractive option.

For completeness, here's what it looks like with [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and a [Lambda Expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

```cpp
#include <functional>

class Light {
public:
  void toggle2() {
  };
};
class Button {
  public:
    Button(int _pin, 
           std::function<void()> single){ // std::function contains the necessary 
                                          // instance reference
        single(); // no muss, no fuss function call
    }
};
Light lights[] = {
  Light()
};
Button buttons[] = {
  Button(1, 
         [](){lights[0].toggle2();}) // lambda expression wrapping the function call
};
```

Comment: What happens if I there's more objects? not only Light, there's too Shutters and Sensors. Also I cannot reproduce your first example, `error: no matching function for call to 'Button::Button(int, void (*)(Light*), Light&)'`

Comment: @RicardoReis Pretty much the same. Pass in one function and one instance variable. If you have a base class with a `virtual void toggle2();` defined, you can pass in the base's `&base::toggle2` function and then many different derived classes the correct derived `toggle2` will be figured out at runtime from the instance used to invoke.

Comment: @RicardoReis This stuff is brutally finicky. Whatever you're passing in looks like `void (*)(Light*)` rather than `void (Light::*)()`. I need to see the `buttons` definition to see exactly what went wrong.